# Is it possible to catch an exception thrown in call to super()?

Tags: java

If, for example, there is a class `c` which has a constructor inside which an exception is thrown while calling `super()` can you catch it from within the constructor?
So, something like this:

```java
class c
{
    c()
    {
        super(c.t());
    }
    static void t()
    {
        throw new java.lang.Throwable();
    }
}
```

This code, of course, does not work. Sure, you can catch it from outside the constructor, and you can not use `try` when calling `super`. Sure. But is there any other way?

Comment: This is not possible. The explanation is clear in [this answer](https://coderanch.com/t/373469/java/catching-exception-parent-constructor#1629992)

Comment: You guys should really post this as an answer so that I can select it and give you reputation for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java Language Specification (JLS) does not allow it:
an explicit constructor invocation (`super(...)` or `this(...)`), if present<sup>**1**</sup>, must be the first statement in a constructor. It is not allowed to be inside a `try-catch` even if the `try` is the first statement.

Probable reason<sup>**2**</sup>:
a constructor is not the same as a method since it does not return any value<sup>**3**</sup>, that is, it cannot simple return `null` if, for some reason (e.g invalid arguments), the object cannot be created. It *must* throw an Exception to *cancel* the instance creation.
As consequence, if a constructor of a parent class throw an Exception, mostly because it cannot or did not initialize its part of the instance, the child class should not be able to ignore this and *swallow* the Exception.

---

**1** - if none is present, the compiler adds a call to `super()` as first statement [JLS 8.8.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7-220).
**2** - this is just my *guess*, eventually not the only reason involved.
**3** - it is the `new` statement that creates the instance, not the constructor [JLS 15.9.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.4).